# printing stack with variable names with gdb?

Tags: c, gdb

I was just reading [this](https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/topic/how-to-exploit-format-string-vulnerabilities/) article.
In the article, the author uses gdb to look around in a c executable.

At one point, when a breakpoint is hit, the author says to have a look at the stack, and shows this output:

```
STACK:

0x00007fffffffdf40│+0x0000: 0x00007fffffffe058  → 0x00007fffffffe380  

0x00007fffffffdf48│+0x0008: 0x0000000100401050

0x00007fffffffdf50│+0x0010: 0x00007fffffffe050  →  0x0000000000000001

0x00007fffffffdf58│+0x0018: 0x0000000000402004  →  “p@ssw0rD”

0x00007fffffffdf60│+0x0020: 0x0000000000000000 ← $rbp

0x00007fffffffdf68│+0x0028: 0x00007ffff7ded0b3  →  <__libc_start_main+243> mov edi, eax

0x00007fffffffdf70│+0x0030: 0x00007ffff7ffc620  →  0x0005043700000000

0x00007fffffffdf78│+0x0038: 0x00007fffffffe058  →  0x00007fffffffe380  →
```

This is nice, but how do I generate this output in gdb?
I've been googling for a while with no luck

Also, in this output there is two different columns of hex adresses, I'm guessing one points to the stack, what is the other one? and which is which?

Answer (score 0):

The author doesn't state it explicitly, but in their gdb output you can see the prompt `gef>`.  This indicates they are likely making use of the [gef](https://gef.readthedocs.io/en/master/) addon for gdb.

I have never used this addon myself, but you can see in some of the example output on the gef site that the addon has a stack view identical to the output you gave above.

The gef addon makes use of gdb's Python API to provide additional features for gdb, one of which appears to be the alternative stack view.